# Count the number of pattern matches in a string

Tags: regex, string, r

For example, I have a string

```
"AAAAAAACGAAAAAACGAAADGCGEDCG"
```

I want to count how many times `"CG"` is repeated.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `gregexpr` to find the positions of `"CG"` in `vec`. We have to check whether there was no match (`-1`). The function `sum` counts the number of matches.

```
> vec <- "AAAAAAACGAAAAAACGAAADGCGEDCG"
> sum(gregexpr("CG", vec)[[1]] != -1)
[1] 4
```

If you have a vector of strings, you can use `sapply`:

```
> vec <- c("ACACACACA", "GGAGGAGGAG", "AACAACAACAAC", "GGCCCGCCGC", "TTTTGTT", "AGAGAGA")
> sapply(gregexpr("CG", vec), function(x) sum(x != -1))
[1] 0 0 0 2 0 0
```

If you have a list of strings, you can use `unlist(vec)` and then use the solution above.

Comment: Thank you again. And now, if I have a list of strings,[1] "ACACACACA"                                                                                     
[2] "GGAGGAGGAG"                                                                     
[3] "AACAACAACAAC"                                                                                    
[4] "GGCCCGCCGC"                                                                               
[5] "TTTTGTT"                                                                                        
[6] "AGAGAGA"     How can I apply the Gregexpr function?

Comment: The function is already vectorised. Do you have a `list` or a `vector`. If a `list` just `unlist( mylist )`

Comment: @lgxqzz I updated the solution and added another one for a vector of multiple strings.

Answer (score 6):

Use `str_count` from `stringr`. It's simple to remember and read, though not a base function.

```
library(stringr)
str_count("AAAAAAACGAAAAAACGAAADGCGEDCG", "CG")
# [1] 4
```

Answer (score 5):

The Bioconductor package Biostrings has a matchPattern function

```
countGC <- matchPattern("GC",DNSstring_object)
```

Note that `DNSstring_object` is FASTA sequence read in using the biostring function `readDNAStringSet` or `readAAStringSet`

Answer (score 2):

In base R, you could use `substring` with a loop to look for the occurrences of `CG`

```
> str <- "AAAAAAACGAAAAAACGAAADGCGEDCG"
> x <- sapply(seq(nchar(str)-1), function(i) substring(str, i, i+1) == 'CG')
> sum(x)
## [1] 4
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be interesting to perform a String processing Functions Benchmark

```
## Data
require("stringi")
vec = paste0(sample(LETTERS, 1e6, replace = TRUE), collapse = "")
df <- data.frame(vec, vec, vec, vec, vec,
                 vec, vec, vec, vec, vec,
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

### Base method
base_fun <- function(x){
  sapply(gregexpr("CG", x), function(x) sum(x != -1))  
}

### Stringi Method
stringi_fun <- function(x){
  sapply(x, function(x) stri_count_fixed(x,"CG"))  
}

### Stringr method
library(stringr)
stringr_fun <- function(x){
  sapply(x, function(x) str_count(x, "CG"))
}


base_fun(df)
# [1] 1441 1441 1441 1441 1441 1441 1441 1441 1441 1441

stringi_fun(df)
# vec vec.1 vec.2 vec.3 vec.4 vec.5 vec.6 vec.7 vec.8 vec.9 
# 1441  1441  1441  1441  1441  1441  1441  1441  1441  1441

stringr_fun(df)
# vec vec.1 vec.2 vec.3 vec.4 vec.5 vec.6 vec.7 vec.8 vec.9 
# 1441  1441  1441  1441  1441  1441  1441  1441  1441  1441

require(rbenchmark)
benchmark(base_fun(df), stringi_fun(df), stringr_fun(df))
# test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
# 1    base_fun(df)          100  17.499    1.000    17.513        0          0         0
# 2 stringi_fun(df)          100  34.897    1.994    34.926        0          0         0
# 3 stringr_fun(df)          100  17.555    1.003    17.564        0          0         0
```

In this particular example, this are the results. Feel free to add, or change whatever them. 
    base_fun(df) = stringr_fun(df) > stringi_fun(df)

**EDIT:** The search engine in stringi 0.2-3 has been drastically improved. New benchmarks (on a different machine):

```
benchmark(base_fun(df), stringi_fun(df), stringr_fun(df))
##              test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
## 1    base_fun(df)          100  26.412   21.214    26.353    0.004          0         0
## 2 stringi_fun(df)          100   1.245    1.000     1.241    0.000          0         0
## 3 stringr_fun(df)          100  26.995   21.683    26.905    0.011          0         0
```

So we have stringi << base = stringr

Comment: Why are you doing this on data.frame and not on vector?

Comment: To see how it scales. A data.frame has several vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Use stri_count_fixed from stringi package

```
require("stringi")

dna=c("a","g","c","t")
N=160
x=sample(dna,N,4)
x2 <- stri_paste(x,collapse="")
stri_count_fixed(x2,"gaga")
## 2
```