# R : Remove words with 3 or more repeating letters using GSUB

Tags: r, gsub, words, repeat

I need to remove words with 3 or more repeating letters from a string using gsub. Example:

"It has been raining verrrry badly heeere last few days"

I need to to get the following using gsub function:

"It has been raining badly last few days". 'verrrry' and 'heeere' words are removed from the string.

Comment: I don't think this is an R thing really, I would recommend looking up "backreferences regex" in google, and you should be able to figure it out. If you're still stuck post your attempt here and I'm sure people will help you.

Comment: new to regex/gsub. need this functionality to embed in R script

Comment: how long is the string you need to remove the words from? are we talking like a whole book or just a few pages?

Comment: this looks like what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21147753/find-the-repeated-characters-in-a-sequence-in-r

Comment: the string is not very big ...would say about a page of text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick search brought up [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644714/what-regex-can-match-sequences-of-the-same-character). Using that you can do something like:

```
## string with repeated letters
s <- "It has been raining verrrry badly heeere last few days"

## split string into vector of words to select
svec <- unlist(strsplit(s, " "))

## find words with 3 or more repeated letters/numbers
## (for any general symbol use '.' instead of '\\w')
rmword <- grep("(\\w)\\1{2, }", svec)

## join words into single string again, removing the unwanted ones
paste(svec[-rmword], collapse = " ")

## output:
[1] "It has been raining badly last few days"
```

***EDIT*** to answer the follow-up request
. Also changed `grep` to `grepl`

First let's wrap the code into a function:

```
rm.repeatLetters <- function(x){
  xvec <- unlist(strsplit(x, " "))
  rmword <- grepl("(\\w)\\1{2, }", xvec)
  return(paste(xvec[!rmword], collapse = " "))
}
```

Then to use it on a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1, 2, 3), text=c(s, s, s), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
## > df
##   id                                                   text
## 1  1 It has been raining verrrry badly heeere last few days
## 2  2 It has been raining verrrry badly heeere last few days
## 3  3 It has been raining verrrry badly heeere last few days


df$text <- sapply(df$text, rm.repeatLetters)
## > df
##   id                                    text
## 1  1 It has been raining badly last few days
## 2  2 It has been raining badly last few days
## 3  3 It has been raining badly last few days
```

Comment: whoa a lot of similar answers popped up in the time I wrote this...

Comment: Thanks Gabe..thanks for sharing the solution. Can you advise how to implement it on a data frame with two columns ID and Text. The processing needs to happen on the Text column.

Comment: Is each text row of the data frame a single word or a full sentence (or paragraph)?

Comment: Each row is a paragraph (in Text Column)

Comment: I just realized you may not get notified that I edited the answer. It's been updated to use it on a data frame.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gabe. I tried running the code on below scenario...it is returning empty values for s2                  [CODE]....                                                                                           s1 <- "It has been raining verrrry badly heeere last few days"
s2 <- "It has been raining very badly here last few days"
s3 <- "It has been raining verrykkk badly heeere last few days"
df <- data.frame(id=c(1, 2, 3), text=c(s1, s2, s3), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df$text1 <- sapply(df$text, rm.repeatLetters)

Comment: Oh oops, that's because when there are no cases `rmword=0` and you can't do `vector[-0]`. It can be changed to a logical instead with `grepl`, try it now.

Comment: Thank you Gabe...it worked!!!

Comment: Glad to know you got it working! If you feel your question was resolved, please consider accepting an answer, whether it's this one or one of the other helpful answers that were provided :)

Answer (score 3):

Option 1

```
x <- "It has been raining verrrry badly heeere last few days"
m <- gregexpr('\\s\\b\\w*(\\w)\\1{2,}\\w*\\b\\s', x, perl = TRUE)
regmatches(x, m) <- ' '
x
# [1] "It has been raining badly last few days"
```

Option 2

```
x <- "It has been raining verrrry badly heeere last few days"
sp <- strsplit(x, ' ')[[1]]
s <- sp[!sapply(sp, function(y) any(rle(strsplit(y, '')[[1]])$lengths >= 3))]
paste(s, collapse = ' ')
# [1] "It has been raining badly last few days"
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution by constructing a regular expression for your case firstly.

```
regExp <- paste(sapply(letters, paste, "{3,}", sep = ""), collapse = "|")
> regExp

"a{3,}|b{3,}|c{3,}|d{3,}|e{3,}|f{3,}|g{3,}|h{3,}|i{3,}|j{3,}|k{3,}|l{3,}|m{3,}|n{3,}|o{3,}|p{3,}|q{3,}|r{3,}|s{3,}|t{3,}|u{3,}|v{3,}|w{3,}|x{3,}|y{3,}|z{3,}"

words <- unlist(strsplit(origStr, "\\s+"))
cleanStr <- paste(words[!grepl(regExp, words)], collapse = " ")
cleanStr
[1] "It has been raining badly last few days"
```

Answer (score -1):

This looks like the output string you're aiming at:

```
origStr = "It has been raining verrrry badly heeere last few days"

newStr <- gsub("e{3,}","e", origStr ) # replaces e's greater than 2 repeat
(newStr <- gsub("r{3,}","r", newStr )) # replaces r's greater than 2 repeat

# [1] "It has been raining very badly here last few days"
```

Comment: Thanks Bob. I wanted the words to be deleted from the string if it has any letter which is repeating more than two times. In my example 'verrrry'  and 'heeere' were deleted as they had letters which were repeating more than two times. Also i am looking for a generic function which can be applied across any word containing any repeating letters....sorry i was not clear earlier. really appreciate your help

Answer (score -1):

Here's one way:

```
library(tm)
data("acq")
acq[[12]]$content -> sometext
tm::MC_tokenizer(x = sometext) -> q
q[131] <- "eeee"

sapply(letters, FUN = function(x) {
    grepl(paste0(x, "{3,}"), x = q, ignore.case = TRUE) -> k
    k
}) -> zz

apply(X = zz, 1, sum) -> flag
q[ifelse(flag == 1, FALSE, TRUE)] -> newq
paste(newq, collapse = " ") -> final
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. Your solutions works. Wondering how can I extend your solution to a data frame (have a data frame with two columns... ID and Text). The processing is happening on the Text field.

Comment: i suggest you use on of the solutions shown abvoe...They are more efficient than the one i gave.